# MityDSP and Ephiphany doubts

Tags: fpga

I've searched the documentation and tutorials about these two families of boards but I have not yet understood something.

Both support ANSI-C and they both have FPGAs, so my doubt is: how is one supposed to program the connection between the cores and the FPGAs? If I write C code in a computer (under Linux for example), pass it to the ARM processors of either Epiphany or MityDSP, are they going to automatically use the C code in the FPGAs? If not, do I need to tell the processors when and how to use the FPGAs? And if so how, because from what I understand FPGAs only accept bitstreams to program themselves.

I know that will seem like a lazy doubt but it is not, believe me. Starting in the FPGAs and IPs' world is a lot confusing and I've searched lots and lots of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be 'lazy lout'?  The adapteva website has various bits out of date and it can be a bit confusing.

The Epiphany based [Parallella](http://www.adapteva.com/parallella/) boards from adapteva have canned [bitstreams](https://github.com/parallella/parallella-hw/tree/master/fpga/bitstreams) for the various product configurations available for download from github.

Presumably the documentation would tell you how to get it loaded. (See [Latest Technical Reference Documents](http://www.adapteva.com/all-documents/)).

The Linux environment, presumably including a programming environment is available on github as well ([Parallella](https://github.com/parallella)).  There's a [Epiphany Architecture Reference Manual (PDF)](http://www.adapteva.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/epiphany_arch_reference_3.12.12.18.pdf) and an [Epiphany SDK](https://github.com/adapteva) also on github.

[MityDSP](http://www.criticallink.com/product-cats/system-on-modules/) support appears more application oriented potentially requiring a commercial relationship with various vendors. Reaching I/O appears to be a matter of custom FPGA programming. (See [MityDSP-L138F](http://www.criticallink.com/product/mitydsp-l138f/) and it's [Spec Sheet](http://www.criticallink.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/MityDSP-L138F_Spec.pdf). Once programmed the FPGA gives access to IO over a 16 bit bus.

The applications for the two boards seem to be divergent.